# Angular 5 Validators.pattern('(0\d{1}|1[0-2])\\/([0-2]\d{1}|3[0-1])\\/(19|20)\d{2}') Not working

Tags: regex, angular, validation

the input field always showing error, could some one help me.

```
var dateRegEx = /^(0\d{1}|1[0-2])\/([0-2]\d{1}|3[0-1])\/(19|20)\d{2}$/;
hiredate: new FormControl({value:null}, Validators.compose([Validators.required,Validators.pattern(dateRegEx)])),
```

This is also not working.

Update: I used the control with mat-datepicker, which setting the control value automatically to javascript date if we input default mm dd yyyy format otherwise it is setting null.

```
                        <mat-form-field>
                                <input matInput id="hiredate" name="hiredate" required [matDatepicker]="picker1" placeholder="Hire Date" formControlName="hiredate">
                                <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                                <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
                                <mat-error *ngIf="isFieldInvalid('hiredate')">
                                    Please provide Hire Date
                                  </mat-error>
                              </mat-form-field>
```

Please check my answer.

Comment: I tried this as well, new FormControl({value:null}, Validators.compose([Validators.required,Validators.pattern(/^(0\d{1}|1[0-2])\/([0-2]\d{1}|3[0-1])\/(19|20)\d{2}$/)])), but still same thing it is not accepting any input in mm/dd/yyyy format

Comment: Try `Validators.pattern('(0\\d|1[0-2])/([0-2]\\d|3[0-1])/(19|20)\\d{2}')`

Comment: when I debug further, it is coming to actual value as date string and comparing with given pattern 
Fri Feb 02 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) which is showing as actual Value, I think, it is the problem

Comment: the mat-datepicker automatically converting input value into date, so the the value of date not matching with given patterns, it is not issue  with pattern, it is due to the behavior of using along with mat-datepicker

Answer (score 0):

After debugging I found that, the underlaying mat-datepicker automatically setting the input value to Date value, and it accepts the default format as mm[-/. ]dd[-/. ]]yyyy if the user inputs in this format, it sets control value as Date value, which is not validated with date pattern. if the user provides in different pattern input, it sets control value as NULL.

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {FormControl} from "@angular/forms";


@Injectable()
export class DateValidator {

   constructor() {
   }

   static date(c: FormControl) {
      //const dateRegEx = new RegExp(/^(0\d|1[0-2])\/([0-2]\d|3[0-1])\/(19|20)\d{2}$/);
     //console.log('Date Value is:',c.value);
     return c.value!=null ? null : {
           dateValidator: {
              valid: false
          }
     };
  }
}
```

and the control defined with validator as

```
hiredate: new FormControl({value:null}, Validators.compose([Validators.required,DateValidator.date])),
```

and now the validator working fine with mat-datepicker